# Inline Images Stripped From Email And Attached

Tags: microsoft-outlook, attachments

When we receive emails (through Kerio/Outlook 2016) from one specific user, any inline images in his messages get stripped out and included as attachments. This can make emails very hard to follow if trying to use screenshots for illustrative purposes for example. His corporate-policy-signature also includes 8(!) images which makes a huge noise-to-signal ratio when looking for the actually relevant images in the attachments.

Because we only see this from that user, and other people in his office can send use embedded images just fine, we assumed the problem was with him somehow. But his IT department swear that his set-up is identical to those of his non-problematic colleagues, and contend the problem is at our end.

It's like his emails are passing through a "plain text" filter somewhere along the line - except they are still HTML and the image links are still there (e.g. `src="cid:image002.png@01D9504F.3B3D1E80"`), but the images don't show inline in the message. I The user is using Office 365.

Is there any way (in the message headers? the source?) to tell how and why the images won't stay inline?

Thanks!

Comment: Despite IT stating all setups are identical, can you ask the *user* if he has any extensions to his mail app, such as sending large files through the cloud, or BTW, Thunderbird *recipients* can display attached images *inline*: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1127923 In View menu, check "Display attachments inline", a possible work-around if the issue cannot be fixed on the sender's end.